# android route specific audio to bluetooth headset

Tags: android, bluetooth, streaming

i'm trying to write an app that will get audio notifications and will stream them on a bluetooth headset. i want this done while other audio frames are playing through the device's speaker (for instance, there is a song playing on another app).
i only want the audio notification to play on the headset, other audio frames should still come out of the speaker.
right now, it doesn't matter whether the other audio frame will pause while the notification is played on the headset or not.
i've looked and found no example of how to do this.
is it at all possible?
can someone direct me?

with regards,
Tamir.

Comment: Sonifications typically have the same routing as `MUSIC` streams - i.e. they will be routed to the same place. Even if you use some other stream type which has a different routing I think you'll find that many phones are using the same audio output interface for the loudspeaker and bluetooth accessories at the ALSA SoC layer, meaning that you as an app developer can't route two concurrent streams to different devices in a reliable manner.

Comment: Hello Michael, Is it possible to fix audio out route at system wide selection at lower level (not app dev)? where should one look for such ? I means routine takes place in which module? E.g devices is connected with speaker, 3.5 wired headphone and bluetooth speaker and want to output on one as per system wide selection.